Ubuntu 24.04 Files display problem: the icons are "missing"
Recently I upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04 and it started this problem. When using files application native from Ubuntu some icons are "missing", kind of glitched and yellow.
It only happens after suspending the laptop.
I have an Acer Nitro 5 from 2020 year with Nvidia Geforce GTX 1050, currently using the nvidia-driver-535(proprietary, tested) with nvidia selected when typing prime-select query on terminal.
This glitch appears also on my login screen/manager screen when i turn on after suspending.


Upgrade pain. Perhaps just deleting the user cache may help: With the terminal: rm -rf ~/.cache. Anything in the cache can be safely deleted, and will be recreated by the application if needed. After doing that, log out then back in. If it works, let us know then I will turn this comment into an answer for the perusal of future readers.

Hey, it didn't work. This only happens after a while I use the PC, if I suspend it and use it later then it will appear.

Add the information from your comment to your question, and also include system details (computer, graphics card). It is likely a problem with suspend on your hardware. Probably there will be no solution as for now other than avoiding the use of the suspend function. If your hardware is rather recent, future versions may cope with the issue.

Thank you so much! I already edited it.
